# JPA query throws the exception

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to save one record into the mysql 5.1 db. When I use entity manager.persist() or merge() method then it is not even saving a record to db and when I try to use native insert statement like this the it throws exception

```
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("insert into Employee(firstName,lastName,phone,email) values(?,?,?,?);");
    query.setParameter(1, employee.getFirstName());
    query.setParameter(2, employee.getLastName());
    query.setParameter(3, employee.getPhone());
    query.setParameter(4, employee.getEmail());
```

Exception thrown from the above query is

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute native bulk manipulation query; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute native bulk manipulation query
```

Please help me !!!!

Thanks

Comment: can we see more of the stacktrace?  I am assuming you are calling executeUpdate on the query.  Why are you using jpa if you are not just saving the employee instance?  The entire point of JPA is to NOT have to do what you are doing.

Comment: Then how can I save this data. I want to use entityManager.persist() or merge() but it is not saving data. Would you please eloborate on how can I save without JPA?

Comment: In addition to Bozho's request for the complete exception and stacktrace, it would probably help if you could post the code for your `Employee` class, especially the way you assign ID's, the `equals()` and `hashcode()` implementation, and the unique constraints you defined (if any).

Answer (score 3):

While I can't immediately help you with the query, because you are most probably omitting an important part of the stacktrace, I have a solution:

Don't use INSERT HQL queries. This is not the way JPA is supposed to work. Instead create a `new Emplyee()` object, which should be an `@Entity`, and set its attributes, then `entityManager.persist(employee)`.

In order for this to work, you need a running transaction. `entityManager.getTransaction().being()` would start one, and `entityManager.getTransaction().commit()` would commit it.

Comment: my dao is @Transactional, so I dont think I need to use begin() and commit(). By the way persist(employee) is not saving data because it throws EntityExist exception. Now if I check in the db there is no record at all. So I am investigating it further....

Comment: Give the whole exception. the whole stacktrace. It _always_ matters.